# Add new attribute to the input of nerual network

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, rnn, lstm

I have few students'(38) sequential data. For example, one student sequential data is like:

```
A
B
B
A
C
D
E
.
.
```

Each student has different length of sequences and their used letter was within this 5 letter. So, to predict the next letter/letters I used feed-forward neural network and recurrent-neural network(LSTM). I got reasonable accuracy with these models.

Now, I want to add a new attribute of the students to the input. Suppose, the students are from four different departments. 
I added the one hot vector of a particular department to the corresponding student.

I used Leave one out as a cross-validation. But for this new input, the testing accuracy is always 100% which is not possible.

My question is, Are there any methods for adding a new attribute to the sequential data?

Answer (score 1):

When adding an attribute, increase the number of neurons in the input layer, then train the network again.

Having 100% accuracy may indicate that the model suffers over-fitting. To solve the problem:

1- make sure that the model doesn't see the test set at training time

2- If you have sufficient number of records, I would recommend going for K-folds validations rather than leave-one out cross-validation (for example 70% training 30% testing)

3- if the number of records is insufficient, (such as in your case: 38 records at best won't allow you go deep), either

- try to get more more data
- or simplify your model (maybe just 1-2 layers with 1-3 neurons!)
- or try machine learning methods other than neural networks. plz see (https://www.cs.sfu.ca/~jpei/publications/Sequence%20Classification.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

> My question is, Are there any methods for adding a new attribute to
>   the sequential data?

The method that you are looking for is exactly called [Transfer Learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfer_learning) in the Machine Learning framework.

In other words, it refers to the case where you train your model based on a situation but you want to generalize to broader or different cases, like the ones where extra attributes are available.

Make sure that you read [this helpful](https://machinelearningmastery.com/transfer-learning-for-deep-learning/) post too.